# How to differentiate the function $\int_x^{100} f(x,y)dy$?

Tags: calculus

How to differentiate the function $\int_x^{100} f(x,y)dy$ with respect to x? Note that x is in the lower bound of the integral.

Edit: This is what I meant:
$\int_x^{100} f(x, y)dy$

Comment: First, use better notation.  Either $\int_x^{100} f(t)dt$ or $\int_x^{100} f(x)dt$, depending on which you mean.

Comment: The integral that you wrote violates the correct format for integrals, and therefore the question does not make sense. You write $x$ in the lower bound of the integral. You also write $x$ as the argument of the function $f(x)$, which presumably is intended to be the variable of integration, but if so then you should have written $\int_x^{100} f(x) \, dx$, or better you should have chosen a different dummy variable of integration like "$t$".

Comment: @LeeMosher edited original post.

Comment: see my edit, you are looking for liebniz integral rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach to figuring out the derivative. For the sake of brevity, I am leaving the exchanging of limits justification to you. Writing

$$H(x) = \int_x^{100} f(x,y) dy$$ then $$H'(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{H(x+h) - H(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac1h \left( \int_{x+h}^{100} f(x+h,y) dy - \int_{x}^{100} f(x,y)dy\right)$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0} \frac1h \left( \int_{x}^{100} [f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)] dy - \int_{x}^{x+h} f(x+h,y) dy \right)$$
$$=\int_x^{100} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) dy - f(x,x).$$

From here we see the same result that Dr. MV and qbert posted.

Note that $\frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h} f(x+h,y) dy$ is the average value of $f(x+h,y)$ over $[x,x+h]$. If $f$ is continuous, then when $h$ is small $f(x+h,y)$ is nearly $f(x+h,x)$ over that interval. So intuitively, the average value should be $f(x,x)$ when $h$ is very small.

Answer (score 3):

If $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ is continuous for $y\in [x,100]$, then [Leibniz's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement) for differentiating under the integral guarantees that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{100} f(x,y)\,dy=-f(x,x)+\int_x^{100} \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\,dy$$

Comment: Thats why the switch gives the negative.

Comment: if $f$ is a function of two variables then what is $f(x)$?

Comment: @Hugh Thank you! I've edited.  The original OP was the integral of a function of one variable only.  It was edited. -Mark

Comment: Why did you reverse your accepting this answer?  That is highly unconventional.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and

$$\int_a^bf(t)dt=-\int_b^af(t)dt$$

Comment: @user1559897 yeah... thats why you flip the bounds. The answer clearly has this written in it... look at the bounds on the integrals. Multiplying by $-1$ flips the bounds

Answer (score 1):

You should know from the fundamental theorem of calculus that $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{100}^x f(t) dt = f(x)$. Now note that by the fundamental theorem $\int_a^b f(t) dt = F(b)-F(a) = -(F(a)-F(b)) = -\int_b^a f(t) dt$ where F is an anti derivative. Therefore, $\frac{d}{dx} \int_x^{100} f(t) dt = -\frac{d}{dx} \int_{100}^x f(t) dt =-f(x)$.

Comment: It's generally considered poor form to use the same variable in the bounds of the integral and the integrand

Comment: @qbert correct you are -- fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus (where *F* is the antiderivative of *f*):
$$\int_x^{100}f(x)dx=F(100)-F(x)$$
$$\frac d{dx} (F(100)-F(x))=-f(x)$$
since 100 is a constant.

Comment: nuts, just beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am assuming that the function is "nice."

If the swapping of bounds confuses you just try evaluating the integral and then differentiating. If $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$ then you want
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(F(100)-F(x))=-F'(x)
$$
since $F(100)$ is just some constant. As you can see, this gives the same answer as the above using the other fundamental theorem of calculus.

edit: OP edited his post to mean something completely different. What OP is asking is how to differentiate under the integral sign, and evaluate
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_x^{100}f(x,y)dy
$$
Assuming $f(x,y)$ is partially differentiable in $x$, and the partial derivative is continous, then the derivative is 
$$
\int_x^{100}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dy+f(x,100)*\frac{d}{dx}(100)-f(x,x)*\frac{d}{dx}x=\int_x^{100}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dy-f(x,x)
$$